# What are \t and \r in byte representation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, byte

```
import sys
for i in range(30):
#     a = int(str(i),base = 16).to_bytes(4,sys.byteorder)
    a = i.to_bytes(4,sys.byteorder)
    print(a)
```

Here `sys.byteorder` seems to be *'little'*. The output of the above code is:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x02\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x03\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x04\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x05\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x06\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x07\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x08\x00\x00\x00'
b'\t\x00\x00\x00'
b'\n\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x0b\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x0c\x00\x00\x00'
b'\r\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x0e\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x0f\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x10\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x11\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x12\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x13\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x14\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x15\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x16\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x17\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x18\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x19\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x1a\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x1b\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x1c\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x1d\x00\x00\x00'
```

Observe integer 9 here is written obnoxiously as `b'\t\x00\x00\x00'` along with similar oddities such as `0xa` and `0xd`.

Is this an aberration or am I lacking knowledge of these notation?
My Python version is 3.8.2.

Comment: You are expecting every byte to be output with a consistent representation. But your code asks for output as bytestings. A bytestring displays printable ascii as characters, uses backslash escapes for nonprinting characters where Python defines them (such as linefeed and tab) and only retreats into hex escapes for the rest. If you have strong feelings about the way the output is formatted, you have ample facilities to do that. The default representation is actually quite useful. For example `b"hello world"` is much friendlier than a bunch of hex escapes.

Comment: I'll say the formatting is significant to me :P
I simply want a code to that converts the numbers in the hex representation we've studied in high school. I began experimenting with numbers as I know full well what to expect. My final intent is to obtain the hex 'string' for any number I enter. I was hoping `to_bytes()` will land me there but it doesn't. What do you recommend I do next?

Comment: Why not just use [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex)?

Answer (score 5):

These are escape sequences.
`\t` represents an ASCII Horizontal Tab (TAB) and `\r` represents an ASCII Carriage Return (CR).

See [Python's documentation of String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: I got it. I just didn't expect them to be here. I want the regular `\x09` and `\x0a`.
And thanks for the edit:)

Answer (score 4):

I think part of the problem is that you are using *bytes* in two senses. It can mean a datatype and it can mean a representation. And you are expecting that a variable of datatype `byte` will have a particular byte representation.

Let's begin by looking at these equivalences:

```
>>> b"\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e" == b"\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e" == bytes([9,10,11,12,13,14])
True
```

As you can see, even though the *representations* of these 6 bytes in Python code differ, the *data* is the same. The middle one is Python's default representation if you just call `print()` on a bunch of bytes.

If you only care about seeing the integer values 0 to 29 displayed as 2 hex digits, then all you need to do is format the integers as 2 hex digits, like this:

```
for i in range(30):
    print (f"{i:02x}")
    
00
01
02
03
...
1b
1c
1d
```

If you want a leading `0x` then put it in the `f`-string before the opening brace.

You can't actually convert your integer value to datatype byte (which is what I think you may have been trying to do with the call to `to_bytes()`) because Python doesn't have a byte datatype. `to_bytes()` returns a `bytes`, which behaves at the Python level like a list of integers in the range 0–255, and its default on-screen representation is a bytestring.

Formatting only affects how the values appear on the screen. If you want the hex representation back in a variable (because you are writing a hex editor, say, and need to manipulate the appearance in your own code), then, as @Harmon758 says, use the `hex()` function:

```
for i in range(30):
    h = hex(i)
    print (h)
```

This gives the same output as `print (f"0x{i:02x}")`, but it is not doing the same thing, because `h` is not an integer, it is a string of length 4. Only the screen representation is the same. If you want the string to look a bit different (a capital `X`, for example, or 4 leading zeroes) you can use an `f`-string instead of calling `hex()`:

```
>>> i = 29
>>> h = f"0X{i:04x}"
>>> h
'0X001d'
>>> h = f"0X{i:04X}"
>>> h
'0X001D'
```

Comment: That's a lot to process at once. But you gave me a much better solution than my approach. I will simulate your explanations to understand it better. Thanks a ton!!