# Python not correctly converting integer into bytes

Tags: python, byte

I want to convert an integer (less than 256) into bytes.

example

`15` → `b'\x0f'`

`255` → `b'\xff'`

Code I ran:

```py
for a in range(256):
  print(a,a.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
```

Some parts are working, but some parts (from 32 to 126) are not working.
I'm getting weird outputs like:

```
33 b'!'
34 b'"'
35 b'#'
36 b'$'
37 b'%'
38 b'&'
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

The whole output:

```
0 b'\x00'
1 b'\x01'
2 b'\x02'
3 b'\x03'
4 b'\x04'
5 b'\x05'
6 b'\x06'
7 b'\x07'
8 b'\x08'
9 b'\t'
10 b'\n'
11 b'\x0b'
12 b'\x0c'
13 b'\r'
14 b'\x0e'
15 b'\x0f'
16 b'\x10'
17 b'\x11'
18 b'\x12'
19 b'\x13'
20 b'\x14'
21 b'\x15'
22 b'\x16'
23 b'\x17'
24 b'\x18'
25 b'\x19'
26 b'\x1a'
27 b'\x1b'
28 b'\x1c'
29 b'\x1d'
30 b'\x1e'
31 b'\x1f'
32 b' '
33 b'!'
34 b'"'
35 b'#'
36 b'$'
37 b'%'
38 b'&'
39 b"'"
40 b'('
41 b')'
42 b'*'
43 b'+'
44 b','
45 b'-'
46 b'.'
47 b'/'
48 b'0'
49 b'1'
50 b'2'
51 b'3'
52 b'4'
53 b'5'
54 b'6'
55 b'7'
56 b'8'
57 b'9'
58 b':'
59 b';'
60 b'<'
61 b'='
62 b'>'
63 b'?'
64 b'@'
65 b'A'
66 b'B'
67 b'C'
68 b'D'
69 b'E'
70 b'F'
71 b'G'
72 b'H'
73 b'I'
74 b'J'
75 b'K'
76 b'L'
77 b'M'
78 b'N'
79 b'O'
80 b'P'
81 b'Q'
82 b'R'
83 b'S'
84 b'T'
85 b'U'
86 b'V'
87 b'W'
88 b'X'
89 b'Y'
90 b'Z'
91 b'['
92 b'\\'
93 b']'
94 b'^'
95 b'_'
96 b'`'
97 b'a'
98 b'b'
99 b'c'
100 b'd'
101 b'e'
102 b'f'
103 b'g'
104 b'h'
105 b'i'
106 b'j'
107 b'k'
108 b'l'
109 b'm'
110 b'n'
111 b'o'
112 b'p'
113 b'q'
114 b'r'
115 b's'
116 b't'
117 b'u'
118 b'v'
119 b'w'
120 b'x'
121 b'y'
122 b'z'
123 b'{'
124 b'|'
125 b'}'
126 b'~'
127 b'\x7f'
128 b'\x80'
129 b'\x81'
130 b'\x82'
131 b'\x83'
132 b'\x84'
133 b'\x85'
134 b'\x86'
135 b'\x87'
136 b'\x88'
137 b'\x89'
138 b'\x8a'
139 b'\x8b'
140 b'\x8c'
141 b'\x8d'
142 b'\x8e'
143 b'\x8f'
144 b'\x90'
145 b'\x91'
146 b'\x92'
147 b'\x93'
148 b'\x94'
149 b'\x95'
150 b'\x96'
151 b'\x97'
152 b'\x98'
153 b'\x99'
154 b'\x9a'
155 b'\x9b'
156 b'\x9c'
157 b'\x9d'
158 b'\x9e'
159 b'\x9f'
160 b'\xa0'
161 b'\xa1'
162 b'\xa2'
163 b'\xa3'
164 b'\xa4'
165 b'\xa5'
166 b'\xa6'
167 b'\xa7'
168 b'\xa8'
169 b'\xa9'
170 b'\xaa'
171 b'\xab'
172 b'\xac'
173 b'\xad'
174 b'\xae'
175 b'\xaf'
176 b'\xb0'
177 b'\xb1'
178 b'\xb2'
179 b'\xb3'
180 b'\xb4'
181 b'\xb5'
182 b'\xb6'
183 b'\xb7'
184 b'\xb8'
185 b'\xb9'
186 b'\xba'
187 b'\xbb'
188 b'\xbc'
189 b'\xbd'
190 b'\xbe'
191 b'\xbf'
192 b'\xc0'
193 b'\xc1'
194 b'\xc2'
195 b'\xc3'
196 b'\xc4'
197 b'\xc5'
198 b'\xc6'
199 b'\xc7'
200 b'\xc8'
201 b'\xc9'
202 b'\xca'
203 b'\xcb'
204 b'\xcc'
205 b'\xcd'
206 b'\xce'
207 b'\xcf'
208 b'\xd0'
209 b'\xd1'
210 b'\xd2'
211 b'\xd3'
212 b'\xd4'
213 b'\xd5'
214 b'\xd6'
215 b'\xd7'
216 b'\xd8'
217 b'\xd9'
218 b'\xda'
219 b'\xdb'
220 b'\xdc'
221 b'\xdd'
222 b'\xde'
223 b'\xdf'
224 b'\xe0'
225 b'\xe1'
226 b'\xe2'
227 b'\xe3'
228 b'\xe4'
229 b'\xe5'
230 b'\xe6'
231 b'\xe7'
232 b'\xe8'
233 b'\xe9'
234 b'\xea'
235 b'\xeb'
236 b'\xec'
237 b'\xed'
238 b'\xee'
239 b'\xef'
240 b'\xf0'
241 b'\xf1'
242 b'\xf2'
243 b'\xf3'
244 b'\xf4'
245 b'\xf5'
246 b'\xf6'
247 b'\xf7'
248 b'\xf8'
249 b'\xf9'
250 b'\xfa'
251 b'\xfb'
252 b'\xfc'
253 b'\xfd'
254 b'\xfe'
255 b'\xff'
```

Comment: What if you take it that it is correct, and you need to change your understanding of what correct means?

Comment: `b' ' == b'\x20'` → `True` It's just a different representation.

Answer (score 0):

[What are \t and \r in byte representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908012/what-are-t-and-r-in-byte-representation)

This aswered my question well.
quote

> I think part of the problem is that you are using bytes in two senses. It can mean a datatype and it can mean a representation.

as  Klaus D. says in the comment,

> `b' ' == b'\x20'` → `True` It's just a different representation.

I wanted to have the output as 2 hex digits but I was getting Python's default representation.

What my code should have looked is

```py
for a in range(256):
  print(a,f"{a :02x}")
```